# foreach - looping through object and changing values - php5

Tags: php, arrays, object, input

I have a simple wee cleansing function in PHP

It takes a value or array of values and does some input cleansing. Now I'm using mysqli which is fetching rows as objects so I need to be able to apply it to obejcts as well as arrays

```
function filter_out($output=''){
    if($output != ''){
        // i.e passed $_POST array
        if(is_array($output)){
            $newoutput = array();
            foreach($output as $outputname=>$outputval){
                $newoutput[$outputname] = stripslashes($outputval);
                $newoutput[$outputname] = htmlspecialchars($newoutput[$outputname]); 
            }
        } else if(is_object($input)){
            ?
        }
    }
}
```

Can anyone tell me how I can do the equivalent with object as input?

Answer (score 3):

The function you're looking for is [`get_object_vars`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.get-object-vars.php):

```
$vars = get_object_vars($input);
foreach ($vars as $outputname => $outputval) {
    ///...
}
```

Don't try iterating on the object itself (`foreach ($object as $key => $value)`), because it won't always work right.  Sometimes it will (`stdClass` as an example), and sometimes it won't (any class implementing [`Traversable`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.traversable.php)...

**Edit**

As far as your comment goes...  As long as the classes aren't doing anything funny (`__get` or `__set`, `protected` or `private`), you could do:

```
$newoutput = clone $input; //make a copy to return
$vars = get_object_vars($input);
foreach ($vars as $outputname => $outputval) {
    $newoutput->$outputname = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($outputval));
}
```

But I can't really think of any method that will work 100% of the time...  The other option, would be to return a nieve object (`stdclass`) instead of the submitted one:

```
$newoutput = new StdClass();
$vars = get_object_vars($input);
foreach ($vars as $outputname => $outputval) {
    $newoutput->$outputname = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($outputval));
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure about: "and sometimes it won't (any class implementing Traversable...", didn't you mean any class **not** implementing Traversable? Unless you meant that "work right" means obtaining all the public properties (as opposed to a custom behavior)?

Comment: @netcoder: No, **any class implementing...** is correct. A class that implements `Traversable` will alter the iteration behavior and will most-likey **not** return the object properties in the iteration.

Comment: @Stefan: Heh, it all depends what your definition of "working right" means. ;-) But I get the idea.

Comment: Thanks, that does the trick though I'm not sure how to set the new vals and return it as an object? - the equiv of what I'm doing with the array? ( should I create new object, somehow dynamically create the property names and set vals ). Hope that made sense!

Comment: @gio: I've edited it in, but read carefully.  There's no 100% foolproof way of doing this.  Without knowing exactly what you're trying to do, I can't really help more than that...

Answer (score 1):

To answer the OP's comment on [ircmaxell's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4411849/foreach-looping-through-object-and-changing-values-php5/4411874#4411874):

```
$vars = get_object_vars($input);
foreach ($vars as $outputname => $outputval) {
    $input->$outputname = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($outputval));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you mention arrays and object coming from mysqli I'm guessing that they're just stdClass so why not just cast the object to an array?

```
$newoutput = array()
foreach ((array) $output as $key => $value) {
  $newoutput[$key] = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($value));
}
```

Or you could probably just do it in place:

```
$output = (array) $output;
foreach ($output as &$value) {
  $value = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($value));
}
```

So a single flow could look like:

```
function filter_out($output=''){
  if($output != ''){
    // i.e passed $_POST array
    $is_array = is_array($output);
    $output = (array) $output;
    foreach($output as &$outputval){
      $outputval = htmlspecialchars(stripslashes($outputval)); 
    }
    if (!$is_array) {
      $output = (object) $output;
    }
  }
  return $output;
}
```